# SAP WebIDE MTA New Build fails since last days with weird zipping issue

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide, sap-cloud-foundry

Our SAP MTA project fails to build since a day or 2 using the new cloud mta build tool option with the following strange error ( I have renamed our actual project name with 'xxx') :

```
11:00:22 (Executor) [2020-02-06 10:00:22]  INFO generating the MTA archive...
11:00:35 (Executor) [2020-02-06 10:00:35]  INFO the MTA archive generated at: /projects/xxx/mta_archives/xxx_cloud_v1_1.0.0.mtar
11:00:35 (Executor) [2020-02-06 10:00:35]  INFO cleaning temporary files...
11:00:35 (Executor) /usr/local/scripts/mbt/webide_mbt_build.sh: line 105: [: mta_archives/xxx_cloud_v1: binary operator expected
11:00:35 (Executor)     zip warning: name not matched: mta_archives/xxx_cloud_v1
11:00:35 (Executor)     zip warning: name not matched: true_1.0.0.mtar
11:00:35 (Executor) 
11:00:35 (Executor) zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r mta_archives/mta_archives.zip . -i mta_archives/xxx_cloud_v1 true_1.0.0.mtar)
11:00:35 (Executor) ERROR:The build of project xxx_cloud_v1 true failed, (Error Code=12, Error Msg=Failed to compress the mta_archives/xxx_cloud_v1 true_1.0.0.mtar source file to the mta_archives/mta_archives.zip .zip file.)
11:00:35 (Executor) ERROR:Function call stack
11:00:35 (Executor)   exitOnError
11:00:35 (Executor)   zipFile
11:00:35 (Executor)   main`
```

It seems like it is confused about the name and adds a space and the value true in between .. causing the ZIP script command to faile.

I have rechecked our MTA.yaml file but don't see anything weird with it.

Other test projects build just fine so it has to be somethinig with either our project work space and/or the script ?

If I try to use the other older build tool option then I am getting a similar script issue:

```
11:19:56 (Executor) The "Task for mta build" process started.
11:19:59 (Executor) Starting process: "cd /projects/xxx_cloud_v1; webide_mta_build.sh"
11:19:59 (Executor) Incorrect command line syntax
11:19:59 (Executor) SAP Multitarget Application Archive Builder 1.1.20
```

We are on SAP Web IDE Full-Stack - Version: 200116.  Production env.

Thanks,

Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been going through all the changes we made on the project over the last couple of days and found the potential source of the issue - although I cannot explain why this is happening.

So for future reference - here is what I found:

We are using quite some properties in the `MTA.yaml` file and a couple new ones where added.

So

```
properties:
    XS_APP_LOG_LEVEL: debug
    CUSTOM_PROP_1: true
    CUSTOM_PROP_2: true
```

It seems that one of those properties is causing the issue - although there is nothing strange with it and it has a `boolean` value like many others we have.

I first thought it would be too long or the combined length would exceed some script variable ... but I can't come to a conclusive answer.

Will be checking with our SAP contacts for further clarification.